# Add new value in var type with old value

Tags: c#, var

i want that my variable  `var repFolderTree` hold old value with new value .

```
 foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
     {

       string strFolderData = row["ReportFolder"].ToString(); 
       var repFolderTree = crcr.GetAllReportsHierarchical(username, strFolderData);
       repFolderTree.FolderName = "All Reports";
       uxAllCatalogHierarchical.Text = string.Format("<div class=\"hierarchicalCatalog\">{0}</div>", HierarchicalCatalogView(repFolderTree, 0, showFolder));
      }





 public CrissCrossLib.Hierarchical.CrcReportFolder GetAllReportsHierarchical(string username,string path)
    {
       var hierItems = GetAllReportsHierarchicalNoCache(username, path);


    m_cacheManager.AllReportsHierarchicalCacheByUsername.Add(username, hierItems);
   return hierItems;
 }





private string HierarchicalCatalogView(CrcReportFolder rootFolder, int level, string showFolder)
        {
            _dt = _ssrsDAC.GetReportListByUser(Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoginID"]));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<div class=\"folderBox\">");
            string scrollTo = "";
            if (PathMatch(showFolder, rootFolder.Path))
                scrollTo = " scrollToFolder";
            sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"folderName{1}\">{0}</div>", rootFolder.FolderName, scrollTo);
            string show = "none";
            if (level == 0 || PathContains(showFolder, rootFolder.Path))
                show = "block";

            sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"folderChildren\" style=\"display:{0}\">", show);

            foreach (CrcReportFolder subFolderLoop in rootFolder.SubFolders)
                sb.Append(HierarchicalCatalogView(subFolderLoop, level + 1, showFolder));

            foreach (CrcReportItem itemLoop in rootFolder.Reports)
            {
                string str = itemLoop.DisplayName;
                DataRow[] foundAuthors = _dt.Select("ReportName = '" + str + "'");
                if (foundAuthors.Length != 0)
                {
                    sb.Append("<div class=\"reportRow\">");
                    sb.AppendFormat("<a class=\"reportLink vanillaHover\" href=\"Report.aspx?path={0}\" >{1}</a>",
                        Server.UrlEncode(itemLoop.ReportPath), itemLoop.DisplayName);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemLoop.ShortDescription))
                        sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"reportInfo\">{0}</div>", itemLoop.ShortDescription);
                    sb.Append("<div class=\"clear\"></div></div>");
                }

               }

            sb.Append("</div></div>");
            return sb.ToString();

        }
```

i have a control where i am listing all the value that i am getting from

`var repFolderTree = crcr.GetAllReportsHierarchical(username, strFolderData);`
so every time loop after that i lost the last value and contain the current value. so i want that i can get all the value after the loop and bind on this control that i am doing in this this line of code

```
uxAllCatalogHierarchical.Text = string.Format("<div class=\"hierarchicalCatalog\">{0}</div>", HierarchicalCatalogView(repFolderTree, 0, showFolder));
```

i think my code make some scene for you .

Comment: You mean you want to pull out the variable? Or do you want to make a list of all values passed. Both questions are answered here a million times already.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Please consider rephrasing the question and also show the code for GetAllReportsHierarchical, what is the return type?

Comment: Do you want to build String? If so you can go with StringBuilder.
Please post some outcome that how do you expect

Comment: yes @PatrickHofman want to pull out the variable so i can use this out of this loop

Comment: Well, probably you need something like `List<T>` where `T` is return type of `GetAllReportsHierarchical`. And then - add item to list at each iteration of your loop

Comment: @Ben i have add the GetAllReportsHierarchical function so you can take a  look and advice me

Comment: That's certainly a small improvement, but what does the object 'CrcReportFolder' contain? Also there needs to be clarification on what you are actually asking, what output do you expect, and what do you want to do with repFolderTree after the foreach loop? For a start repFolderTree  is within the scope of the foreach loop and therefore will  not exist once the foreach loop is completed... Perhaps your answer is simple, move repFolderTree to before the loop.

Comment: @Ben i add more description with function hope this help you to understand

Answer (score 0):

you can use List or Collection to store all the values , with Add operation to add the var value.

```
 List<object> repFolderTree = new List<object>();
 foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
     {

       string strFolderData = row["ReportFolder"].ToString(); 
       var repFolderTree = crcr.GetAllReportsHierarchical(username, strFolderData);
repFolderTree .Add(repFolderTree );
       repFolderTree.FolderName = "All Reports";
       uxAllCatalogHierarchical.Text = string.Format("<div class=\"hierarchicalCatalog\">{0}</div>", HierarchicalCatalogView(repFolderTree, 0, showFolder));
      }
```